# Getting all Foursquare categories that respond to a query term in their API

Tags: foursquare

I'm currently exploring Foursquare's API and I was wondering if there was any way I could figure out which categories respond to a certain search term (query). There doesn't seem to exist such an option in Foursquare, so I'm guessing this probably has to be done indirectly.

What I am trying to do is getting their [API](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) to tell me which category(ies) (IDs are enough) respond to a query term. For instance, if my query was `donuts`, how can I get an array that would contain all the related categories `categoryID`?

I don't mind if I don't hit **all** their results, I'm fine with being restricted to a certain area. I would like, though, that even if there might not exist venues related to a certain query in a location, if that query term is known to be related to a certain category, I would be aware of it - for instance, no `donuts` nearby, but Foursquare knows it relates to `Bakery` category.

I already know that if I `search` using a query term, they'll supply a list of venue results and I could scrap it for all the categories. I'm just wondering if there is a more clever and API friendly way of doing this, since I don't want (nor is it allowed, by [their terms](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/community)) to scrap their DBs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible since there could be a bar called 'donuts' that doesn't relate to bakeries at all. Like you mentioned, I would hit the [venue/explore](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore) endpoint with limit=10 and 'rank' the top categories returned.